# Iterating through class variables in python

Tags: python-3.x

Please correct my code

PS - i'm fairly new to python

```
class Contact:
    def __init__(self,cid, email):
        self.cid=cid
        self.email=email
def ind(contacts):
    index={}
    #Code here
    return index
contacts = [Contact(1,'a'),
      Contact(2,'b'),
      Contact(3,'c'),
      Contact(4,'a')]
print(ind(contacts))
```

Need the output to be like -

```
{'a':[1,4], 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following methods create list values like:

```
{'a':[1,4], 'b':[2], 'c':[3]}
```

I can't imagine why this wouldn't be fine, but I've added a method at the end that gets your specific output.

This doesn't maintain order of the emails:

```
def ind(contracts):
    index={}
    for contract in contracts:
        index.setdefault(contract.email, []).append(contract.cid)
    return index
```

To maintain order (e.g. start with 'a'), add `from collects import OrderedDict` to the top of your file and then the method is:

```
def ind(contracts):
    index = OrderedDict()
    for contract in contracts:
        index.setdefault(contract.email, []).append(contract.cid)
    return index
```

The printout of `index` will look different, but it acts the same as a normal `dict` object (just with ordering).

**Exact output (with ordering):**

```
def ind(contracts):
    index = OrderedDict()
    for contract in contracts:
        if contract.email in index:
            value = index[contract.email]
            if not isinstance(value, list):
                index[contract.email] = [value]
            index[contract.email].append(contract.cid)
        else:
            index[contract.email] = contract.cid
    return index
```